# Problems using node-restify-oauth2-mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, oauth, restify

I would like to use Restify/Nodejs + Oauth2 + Mongodb to register and authenticate users... I found a great git hub repo here:

https://github.com/rgallagher27/node-restify-oauth2-mongodb

I have both Redis and Mongo installed and I get the node up and running with the code and I can register users. However, I have some problems with validating a user. There was one step in the instructions that I am not sure I am completing correctly ...

```
//////////////////////
**Insert a Client Key into the mongoDB wit the format:** 

{
    _id: ObjectId("51c6e846ede91c0b8600005e"),
    clientName: "Test Client",
    client: "test",
    secret: "password"
}
//////////////////
```

Should this be a mongo db as in

```
db.ClientKey.insert({_id: ObjectId("51c6e846ede91c0b8600005e"), clientName: "Test Client", client: "test",  secret: "password"});
```

or is this a collection?

I have tried both to no avail.

I believe my failure to understand how this should be created in mongoDB may be causing my issues with an inability to validate a user

in mongodb my restify_test db has a "users" collections... which appears as

```
> db.users.find();
{
    "name" : "Test",  
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "username" : "tester1", 
    "hashed_password" : "$2a$10$67rLfuKQqHIwHc2tOPNu.ejY.L/5Mk6XnuOdn0xc9UXUyzKBs6NQC",
    "_id" : ObjectId("520d5874421b580000000001"),
    "role" : "Admin", 
    "__v" : 0
}
>
```

But when i try to curl the login

```
$ curl --user test:password --data grant_type=password --data username=tester1 --data password=testing27 http://[my-localhost]:8090/token
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client ID and secret did not validate."}
```

Once again I thank you for any direction you can give me here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem as you when using this insert statement:

```
db.ClientKey.insert({_id: ObjectId("51c6e846ede91c0b8600005e"), clientName: "Test Client", client: "test",  secret: "password"});
```

The thing that I noticed was the if I did **show collections** in mongo, one collections was called **users** and the other was **ClientKey**. With some trial and error I worked out that the collection needed to called **clientkeys** (note the plural and lowercase). You should be able to run these commands to fix the issue (assuming you're working from the command line):

```
mongo
use restify_test
db.ClientKey.renameCollection("clientkeys")
```

Once I did this, executing the curl command correctly returned my access_token and token_type.

Hope that helps!