# invalid_client on initial setup of node-restify-oauth2-mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, mongoose, restify

My question is similar to this question that did not accept an answer:
[Problems using node-restify-oauth2-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263276/problems-using-node-restify-oauth2-mongodb)

However, mine is a little different in that `clientKeys` collection is named correctly or at least I think so.

When I go into my mongo instance and look at my collections I have:

```
clientkeys
users
```

When I look at what is in those collections I see:

```
> db.clientkeys.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51c6e846ede91c0b8600005e"),
    "clientName" : "Test Client",
    "client" : "test",
    "secret" : "password"
}

> db.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543d7b974f1870f131c6d0aa"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "username" : "tester1",
    "hashed_password" : "$2a$10$gpMXyCuILBbMF2K6Aroc7.lKoIpuGhvL98ZGGoE0tEOtYSQaCpMde",
    "role" : "Admin",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I follow the direction in the repo:
https://github.com/rgallagher27/node-restify-oauth2-mongodb

So I run this:

```
curl --data "name=Test&email=test@test.com&username=tester1&password=testing27&vPassword=testing27&role=Admin" http://localhost:8090/register
```

Which it responds how he says, like this:

```
{
    "__v":0,
    "name":"Test",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "username":"tester1",
    "hashed_password":"$2a$10$3uwD9IiKVlkQJvdQXqm07uQnfcXae3AGjDh.zil8.8CgtlQ2MuACK",
    "_id":"520774753472d74e2c000001",
    "role":"Admin"
}
```

Then I run the following command:

```
curl --user test:password --data grant_type=password --data username=tester1 --data password=testing27 http://localhost:8090/token
```

This however returns:

```
{
    "error":"invalid_client",
    "error_description":"Client ID and secret did not validate."
}
```

I can't quite figure out what I am missing. Unless I am using the wrong collection name for my `clientkeys` but I don't think I am.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: I looked through and it looked like the collection should be called `ClientKey` based on this line in `hooks.js`.

    `var Client      = mongoose.model('ClientKey');`

I changed my collection in mongo and that still didn't work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after walking through the process I found that in the `hooks.js` they are receiving the wrong params for `validateClient` line 35 and `grantUserToken` line 52.

Here is what you will need to change to make this app work.

line 35

```
exports.validateClient = function (clientId, clientSecret, cb)
```

to

```
exports.validateClient = function (clientCredentials, req, cb)
```

line 39

```
Client.findOne({ client: clientId, secret: clientSecret }, function (err, client) {
```

to

```
Client.findOne({ client: clientCredentials.clientId, secret: clientCredentials.clientSecret }, function (err, client) {
```

line 52

```
exports.grantUserToken = function (username, password, cb)
```

to

```
exports.grantUserToken = function (allCredentials, req, cb)
```

line 54

```
var query = User.where( 'username', new RegExp('^' + username + '$', 'i') );
```

to

```
var query = User.where( 'username', new RegExp('^' + allCredentials.username + '$', 'i') );
```

line 61

```
} else if (user.authenticate(password)) {
```

to

```
} else if (user.authenticate(allCredentials.password)) {
```

line 65 and 66

```
var token       = generateToken(username + ":" + password);
var newToken    = new Token({ username: username, token: token });
```

to

```
var token       = generateToken(allCredentials.username + ":" + allCredentials.password);
var newToken    = new Token({ username: allCredentials.username, token: token });
```

line 70

```
redisClient.set(token, username);
```

to

```
redisClient.set(token, allCredentials.username);
```

Hope this helps someone and let me know if anyone else has a better solution. This worked for me.

Now when I run this

```
curl --user test:password --data grant_type=password --data username=tester1 --data password=testing27 http://localhost:8090/token
```

This is my response

```
{
    "access_token":"S7QEwABRiv6HCSaXy70mUlxY7i/Un/EcgWpvbrBhXlw=",
    "token_type":"Bearer"
}
```

Now for the secret routes still in the `hooks.js` change line 80

```
exports.authenticateToken = function (token, cb)
```

to

```
exports.authenticateToken = function (token, req, cb)
```

If you run this command

```
curl -H "Authorization:Bearer Your-Bearer-Token" http://localhost:8090/secret
```

Your response will be

```
{
    "message":"Success"
}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I used the same code .. and it works .. I think you didn't insert entry correctly for model ClientKey..thats clear from the feedback message.

it should be :

```
db.clientkeys.insert({  
   clientName:"Test Client",
   client:"test",
   secret:"password"
})
```

Note the name of collection **clientkeys** not **ClientKey** neither **ClientKeys** .. it should follow the module name + s ..

Comment: it was more than just the collection name, thanks for the post